# How do I emulate a database in memory only lasting during the runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, in-memory-database

I'd like to emulate a database operations using *DbContext* and use EF to operate on my models but without an actual database being installed. Is it possible (fairly easily) in .NET Core (version 2.2 if it makes any difference)?

I've read about *AddXxxInMemory* methods but only in the context of Identity Server. Eventually I'll have a persistent data source but on occasion, I'd like to have a faked one just in memory, populate it by a seed and not rely on an external DB being installed.

Is that possible at all? My googling created mostly confusion and drowned in the guides on how to connect to SQL Server and for some weird reason also links to IMDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework Core provides a in-memory database. It's initially designed for unit-tests, but it can be used for other purposes.

The full documentation is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/

```
[TestMethod]
public void Add_writes_to_database()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database")
        .Options;

    // Run the test against one instance of the context
    using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
    {
        var service = new BlogService(context);
        service.Add("http://sample.com");
    }

    // Use a separate instance of the context to verify correct data was saved to database
    using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, context.Blogs.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual("http://sample.com", context.Blogs.Single().Url);
    }
}
```

Comment: The examples concentrate on the usage of in-memory DB for testing. How would I go about to make it available in my controller during a manual test-run? I understand that I should use a constructor like `public MyClass(MyDbContext c)` but how do I make it work? I can register it using DI as a scoped service (or possibly singelton) but it feels like there's more to be done that the guide doesn't tell.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana, after installing InMemory Nuget package you will be able to register DbConext in the Startup with `.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "something")` option